# Gradient options via Wand

Tags: wand

I have installed the most recent versions of ImageMagick (7.0.8-27 Q16 x64 2019-02-09) and Wand (0.5.1) on a Windows 7 computer.

I would like to know if the gradient options can be used in Wand—the options that are listed on https://imagemagick.org/script/gradient.php, that can be set using the -define argument in command line.

I know that the following Wand code generates a gradient.

```
wand.image.Image(width=100, height=100, pseudo='gradient:white-black')
```

Is it possible to use the gradient options via Wand?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Although it's a little awkward in python. You need to set the property before reading the image. Usually like:

- Allocate an instance of wand w/o an image
- Set the definition on `Image.options` dict.
- Read pseudo format

For example...

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image() as img:
    img.options['gradient:vector'] = '10,10,75,75'
    img.pseudo(256, 256, 'gradient:white-black')
    img.save(filename='output.png')
```

[image: gradient option]